# What is wrong with this jquery statement.?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dialog

I'm having the following code. Everything seems to work fine but its just that some times, there are times whereby the confirm and alert notices appear multiple times and they just get overly annoying. Is there any problems with the following code. Thanks for any advice.

```
    $('.order_stateselect').hover(function(){
        var value_text=$(this).find(":selected").text();
        var value_code=$(this).find(":selected").val();
        $(this).change(function(){
            if(confirm('Confirm Order Status Change?')){
                var conduct_status_chge=$.post('/seller/helpers/order_status_change.php',{order_item_id:$(this).parent('td').siblings('.order_item_id').text(),order_item_status:$(this).find(':selected').val()},function(data){
                    alert(data);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $(this).find(':selected').removeAttr('selected');
                    $(this).find('option:contains(value_code)').attr('selected','selected');
                    alert('error');

                });
            }else{
                $(this).find(':selected').removeAttr('selected');
                $(this).find('option:contains(value_code)').attr('selected','selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

A brief explanation of what i'm doing here.

This is a selectbox with multiple options. This selectbox is part of a table cell in a list of items.

ie: Meaning that each row contains an item and for each row, there is a a selectbox dedicated to that specific row.

1) Upon hover, i get the values of the selected option loaded via my database value when the page loads.

2) When the user selects a different value from the selectbox and confirm selection, i do a $.post.

3) If user press cancel or if there is an error with the script call that causes the the $.post to fail, i revert the selected option back to the original value from database.

I'm sorry if my explanation is abit unclear but please let me know if you guys need anymore information. thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is that you assign an event to '.order_stateselect' multiple times in 'hover'. And why would you need the 'hover' at all? Try to just put all the code in the 'change' event.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take a small excerpt from your code:

```
$('.order_stateselect').hover(function(){
    var value_text=$(this).find(":selected").text();
    var value_code=$(this).find(":selected").val();
    $(this).change(function(){
```

You're attaching a change handler when the mouse cursor enters the area; if this happens multiple times, your change handler also gets applied multiple times.

You should move the `.change(...)` outside of the `.hover()`:

```
$('.order_stateselect')
    .hover(function() { ... })
    .change(function() { ... })
```

Comment: Hmm. This can't work, if i were to seperate out the both, I will not be able to revert back to its original value. Both value_text and value_code will be rendered useless because they will not be able to get the values i need.

Comment: @Lawrence Easy, just add the previous selected value using `.data()`; then, inside the `.change()` you can refer to those values and updated them if the user confirmed.